# View Caching with PHP

Tags: php, caching, view, include, intercept

I have a question about the cache of a view, suppose I have the following block of code:

```
<?php
    class View {          
        public function render ( $template , $path = null ) { } 
            // ...  
        }
```

This is my 'MainView', in which the class is extended in all other views, such as 'ClientsView' .. etc.

But, I wanted to implement a way to intercept the request of the surrender, through a cache, I say to the cache when I pass this parameter to the render method, or something .. I just wanted to keep control .. so I have a 'ViewCacheStorage', where you will store the files that are cached, and the remaining time to expiration of each cache, what is the best way to do this without me having to shake the main view?

Comment: http://www.reocities.com/tablizer/myths.htm

Comment: What do you mean by "without having to shake the main view"?

Comment: without adding code to create the view cache in the main view.

Comment: Why does the render method has parameters when it's a view?

Comment: because this method is to render the template, it is called by other views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy option:

```
class CachingView extends View {

    protected $cacheStorage;

    public function render($template, $path = null) {
        if (! $this->getCacheStorage()->has($template)) {
           $this->getCacheStorage()->store(parent::render($template, $path));
        }

        return $this->getCacheStorage()->get($template);
    }

    public function getCacheStorage() {
        if (empty($this->cacheStorage)) {
            $this->cacheStorage = new ViewCacheStorage();
        }
        return $this->cacheStorage;
    }
}
```

And then all your other views extend from CachingView.

Comment: in this case, the classes that I need to cache, is it?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but I've updated my code to include a CacheStorage class - maybe it's clearer for you now.